# How to change the current directory in a file/open requester [file-picker] by clicking an open Finder window below?

Tags: finder

Years ago I've seen a great UX solution on a Mac:

- in a program, say, a text editor, I choose File/Open menu,
- the file open dialog comes up, with a default directory, e.g. Desktop,
- I click on a Finder window, or the desktop itself, and the open dialog directory changes to the clicked window.

I found it pretty useful, because the user opens directories in Finder because he or she actually works with them, and it's trivial that he or she will open/save stuff in one of these directories.

Is there such extension out there, or my false memory is kidding with me?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine this to be the UX solution you've seen:

### Favorite folders in the Finder sidebar

1. Show the sidebar. Choose **View > Show Sidebar**. (If Show Sidebar is dimmed, choose View > Show Toolbar.)
2. **Add a folder**: Hold down the Command (⌘) key, then drag the item to the Favorites section.

If you don’t see the Favorites section, go to Finder > Preferences > Sidebar, then select at least one item in the section.

Is this the solution you were looking for?

---

Original answer

To navigate to a folder in the "file/open dialog" that is already open in Finder.app do this:

(I assume that both the Finder window and the "file/open dialog" are visible on the same screen/space)

1. **Click and hold the folder** icon of the folder you want to go to and…
2. Drag the **icon into the "file/open dialog**" and release the mouse.
3. Done.

Comment: I knew this trick, but I'm looking the use-finder-windows-as-kinda-bookmarks feature.

Comment: I think I know which feature you're looking for. I'll edit my answer in a few hours. I. The meantime: in Finder.app show the left sidebar. You'll see a section called "favorites". Drag your folders onto it. Now you can click any of your bookmarked folders to go there instantly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the app you're looking for is [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html)
It does a myriad other things, but clicking in an open Finder window on the desktop will take the dialog to it [even if not visible behind another app or window]

It will 'bookmark' folders, historically or as Favourites & you can set up different sets for different apps & workflows.

[image]

Well worth the price imho; I've been using it since before they added the 'X' to the title, in OS 9 & earlier. I consider it one of my 'cannot live without' utilities.
*No affiliation, just a long-time happy user.*

Copy/paste of their Main Features section...

> **Directory Assistant**
> Access your recent, favorite, and open folders from DFX's toolbar. Hierarchical pop-up menus let you quickly
> navigate through folders to get to your files.
>
> **Real Time Saving**
> If you're constantly saving things inside the same folder, DFX can remember that folder for you. Or you can set it
> as the default folder for an application so you're in the right folder
> from the start.
>
> **Finder Management**
> DFX lets you open up or save to any Finder window with a single click. It also lets you get info on, duplicate,
> rename, and delete existing files, putting the Finder's power in every
> Open and Save dialog.
>
> **Instant Recall**
> To help you quickly return to folders and files you've used recently, DFX remembers them for you. It even re-selects
> the last file you opened. With DFX, you'll never forget where you put
> something.
>
> **At Your Fingertips**
> Get places fast by using keyboard shortcuts for your favorite folders. Or jump to recent folders and open Finder
> windows with a keystroke. DFX's shortcuts are completely
> configurable.
>
> **Spotlight on the Spot**
> Tag your files or edit your Spotlight comments from within any Open or Save dialog. Don't remember what tags
> you used before? DFX shows you all of your recently used tags - just
> drag and drop.