# How can I set a default save location for Stickies?

Tags: finder, applications, filesystem, file

Every day I take notes on a morning meeting in the Stickies app. At the end of the week, I save all the sticky notes to a folder for archiving purposes. I close the sticky, and when asked weather I'd like to save the note I say yes.

The save dialogue opens to my home folder by default. I then have to navigate to the folder where I store my stickies *every time*. It's a little bit deeply nested so I find this annoying.

Why doesn't the save dialogue open to the last location where I saved a sticky note, like it does for most applications? Is there a way to change the default save location from my home folder to this custom folder?

Comment: That's why DefaultFolder was invented ;) It might be overkill for a single app, but I find it very useful - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269949/85275